# Function returning a value from a MySQL database in Twisted

Tags: python, mysql, database, twisted

I have a MySQL database that contains several tables that have a structure like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE (`key1`)
);
```

In my Python program that uses the Twisted framework, I need to perform a series
of mostly identical operations with each one of these tables:

1. Check if a given value is present in the `key` column of the table.
2. If it is, return its corresponding `id`.
3. If it is not, insert that value into the table and return its corresponding `id`.

Since the operations are essentially identical, it would make sense for this
action to be performed by a function that takes the table and the key names,
as well as the value as arguments and returns the id.

How can I do this? I can't do

```py
import MySQLdb

from twisted.python import log
from twisted.enterprise.adbapi import ConnectionPool
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks

class ReconnectingConnectionPool(ConnectionPool):
    def _runInteraction(self, interaction, *args, **kw):
        try:
            return ConnectionPool._runInteraction(
                self, interaction, *args, **kw)
        except MySQLdb.OperationalError as e:   # pylint: disable=no-member
            if e[0] not in (2003, 2006, 2013):
                raise e
            conn = self.connections.get(self.threadID())
            self.disconnect(conn)
            # Try the interaction again
            return ConnectionPool._runInteraction(
                self, interaction, *args, **kw)

dbh = ReconnectingConnectionPool(
    'MySQLdb',
    db='database',
    user='user',
    passwd='password'
)

@inlineCallbacks
def get_id(table, column, entry):
    try:
        r = yield dbh.runQuery("SELECT `id` FROM `{}` WHERE `{}` = '{}'".format(table, column, entry))
        if r:
            id = r[0][0]
        else:
            yield dbh.runQuery("INSERT INTO `{}` (`{}`) VALUES ('{}')".format(table, column, entry))
            r = yield dbh.runQuery('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()')
            id = int(r[0][0])
    except Exception as e:
        log.msg(e)
        id = 0
    return id
```

because the function `get_id` is a generator and those can't return values directly.

Should I use `defer.returnValue(id)` instead of `return id`? Or should I use `dbh.runQuery('query').addCallback(get_result)`
where `get_result` is a function like this

```py
def get_result(value):
    return value
```

Or should I do something else?

Answer (score 0):

the `get_id` function itself will returns a `deferred` since you use `inlineCallbacks` to wrap it.

then you call your function with:

`get_id().addCallback(your_callback_to_retrive_the_id)`

in your `get_id` function if you are using python3 you can use `return`  or `defer.returnValue` statement to return the result.

In python2 you can only use `defer.returnValue`

```
from __future__ import print_function

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred, returnValue, inlineCallbacks



def runQuery(query):
    # suppose this will fetch the result from database
    d = Deferred()

    # simulate the delay waiting for the database to give the results
    # using reactor.callLater
    reactor.callLater(0.3, d.callback, 1); # 1 here is the (result)
    return d


@inlineCallbacks
def get_id(table, column, entry):
    r = yield runQuery("foobar")
    # r is the result from the database
    #if python3
    return r # or returnValue(r)

    # if python2
    # returnValue(r)


# every time you call a function that is wrapped with inlineCallbacks
# the return value of that function is Deferred

d = get_id('messages', 'message', 'Foo')
d.addCallback(lambda r: print("Result: %r" % (r, )))

reactor.run()
```

Comment: Ah, so I have to add the callback to `get_id` instead of to `runQuery`? Also, how would I actually get the result? In other words, how would `your_callback_to_retrieve_the_id` in your example look? Will it be like `get_result` in mine? The Twisted documentation shows only how to add procedures as callbacks but never how to actually add a function that returns a value...

Comment: No, this doesn't work. When I try to add a callback to `get_id`, I get an error message  `Generator 'generator' has no 'addCallback' member`.

Comment: how do you call it exactly?

Comment: and also we can only use callback attached to a deferred to retrieve the result from function returning a deferred. The result is given to you via the first callback parameter.

Comment: I call it more or less like this: `message_id = get_id('messages', 'message', 'Foo').addCallback(get_result)`. I am afraid I don't understand what you are saying about getting the result. Could you please edit your answer to include a full, working piece of code?

Comment: I have edited my answer to add code that try to mimic your case

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't understand how this is an answer to my question. Just like in the examples in the Twisted documentation, your callback is a procedure (`print`) - not a function. I don't want to print the result of the query - I want to return it as a value, from a function, and to store it in a variable that I could use later.

Comment: Your code is asynchronous, it tried to fetch result from an external resource (database) in this case, without waiting for the result (the result will be available later)  and without blocking. And that is why every async operation in twisted give a result as a deferred. That deferred will be a placeholder for future result and attach a callback to it to process/retrieve the eventual result.
The purpose of the `inlineCallbacks` is to make your code look synchronous but actually it run asynchronous, the key with `inlineCallback` is, put everything in a function and process everything in it.